# How is Gollum dressed in the books?

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings, tolkiens-legendarium, the-hobbit, clothing

In Jackson films, Gollum is dressed in loincloth.

What was his manner of dress (in Hobbit/LOTR timeframe) in the books?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's never fully described, but in *The Hobbit* at least he has **pockets**, in which to keep "a tooth sharpening rock, goblin teeth, wet shells, and a scrap of bat wing". See e.g. the following quote:

> [Gollum] was on his island (of which, of course, Bilbo knew nothing), scrabbling here and there, searching and seeking in vain, and turning out his pockets.
>   <sub>-- *The Hobbit*, chapter *Riddles in the Dark*</sub>

In *The Lord of the Rings*, the best I can find is a reference to his "**ragged garments**" (Book 4, Chapter III: *The Black Gate is Closed*).